# refer to parent when setting css element

Tags: css, less

I have this CSS shared between pages and I want to only do some padding change on one page of them an the rest will still be the same .

I can do that through creating  a special class for the page I am using , but I want to ask if there is a neat way to handle it by adding a condition on the top parent in page ?

needed change : if the top parent in page has some id / class name .. do padding-top: 60px instead of 30px ,,else keep it 30px

```
#box-list {
  padding-top: 10px;

  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right this will work.

The only condition is that there is a parent of `#box-list` with an id `#your-special-page`.

```css
#box-list {
  padding-top: 10px;

  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    padding-top: 30px;

    #your-special-page & {
      padding-top:60px;
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: He seems to be using LESS but this solution works just fine for LESS as well. Just confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 if (".top parent").hasClass("some_class"){

    $("#box-list").css("padding-top", "60px");

 }else{
     $("#box-list").css("padding-top", "30px");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to generate some CSS like this:

```css
#box-list {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.special-template #box-list {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

In LESS or Sass you could write something like this:

```less
#box-list {
    padding-top: 10px;

    .special-template & {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that the `&` sing references the whole selector before. So If you have additional levels you may getting some wired results at the beginning.